# "Anyone" or "everyone" in the context?

Tags: grammar

Tell me please which word I have to use in the following context.

> I know how to use the computer,andI guess **everyone**/**anyone** knows how to use it nowadays.

I cannot see any difference in the meaning of the sentence if use any pronoun. Is there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Everyone" means most people or many people, but if you use "anyone", it means even people who aren't smart know how to use it. "Everyone" is neutral, "anyone" is not.